# Increase font size in zend studio

Tags: php, editor, zend-studio

I am using zend studio since last 3 years, but do not know how can we continuously increase or decrease font size. like in some editors we use ctrl++ and ctrl+- and in some ctrl and mouse wheel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The alternative I font is

Inside Zend Studio:

```
Window
Preferences
general
appearance
colors and fonts
Basic
Aa Text Font
Edit
```

There you go...

Comment: This is a very short shortcut! All other software(like Photoshop,Word,Notepad++ etc,etc...) should use the same method for in-/decreasing. Window->Preferences->general->appearance->colors and fonts->Basic->Aa Text Font->Edit is a much faster solution.

Comment: all windows fonts are increasing but not the font of actual code